# Flask Model with GeoAlchemy column

Tags: flask, model, geom-text

> How to create the geometry column in flask model

```
   from geoalchemy2 import Geometry
   from app import db
   class process(db.Model):
      wkt = db.Column(Geometry('POINT'))
```

But it's gives error while creating the table

```
create table process(
[WKT] geometry(GEOMETRY,-1) NULL)
```

SQL Error Is:

```
Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's tricky, I tried  this one

```
WKT = db.Column(Geometry(''))
```